# How to change the color of a check in a checkbox | CSS

Tags: html, css

How can we change the color of a check in a checkbox. i was trying to make my checklist like this -

[image]

Mine looks like this -

[image]

i was trying to accomplish it using CSS

```
 input[type="checkbox"]{
    color:brown;
}
```

You can see the full code on Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/31pv9cop/

Comment: You won't be able to. Checkboxes, together with a lot of other form-elements, are subject to the OS/browser default styling. To get what you want, you will have to use other elements to mimic the checkbox, together with using pseudo-classes.

Comment: Using just CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/5g3w32ug/

Else I would use images and toggle them.